# Replace text at specific position

Tags: python

I am trying to use the replace function to replace specific spans in a text. But it ends up replacing all same strings.

```
text = "I played 13 times and 134 other times"
spans = [[9,11],[26,31]]

for i in spans:
    text = text.replace(text[i[0]:i[1]], "*"*len(text[i[0]:i[1]]))
```

prints `'I played ** times and **4 ***** times'`

replacing 13 in 134 too.

Is there another way to replace this more accurately?

Comment: Add `count=1` to your call to `.replace`.

Comment: @MattDMo Would this not fail if there is another  "13" with unique indices later in the text that should be replaced?

Comment: It'll only replace what exists in the string. Say `13` exists in the string 3 times, and you want to replace the first two. After the first one is replaced, the next time it's called with the string `"13"` it'll automatically replace the second instance, because the first will be `"**"` at that point. However, this code will not work if you want to replace the first and *third* instances, because `.replace` automatically begins at the beginning of the string. You'll probably need to use regex in that case, or at least do more string manipulations.

Comment: you could use more readable `for start, end in spans: ... text[start:end]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does what you want. It creates a new string grabbing everything up to the beginning of the span, then adds the *** and then everything after the span. Because you are replacing text with `*` characters instead of deleting it, the length of the string stays the same after this operation, and we are able to continue to do this for the next span (the indices of the next span will still point to the correct characters to replace).

```
text = "I played 13 times and 134 other times"
spans = [[9,11],[26,31]]

for i in spans:
    text = text[:i[0]] + '*'*(i[1]-i[0]) + text[i[1]:]
```